# Which languages did Søren Kierkegaard speak and which could he only write/read?

Tags: language, kierkegaard

I have read that Kierkegaard besides his mother tongue danish only learned to **speak** a little german.

But he off course knew how to **read** and **write** greek and latin very well.

But how about other languages?

**Related language anecdote:** 
When Kierkegaard lived the rule in Denmark was that dissertations were mandatory to be written in latin, but Kierkegaard  applied to the danish King for a dispensation from the rules. His dissertation was therefore written in danish, but he made his verbal defense in latin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See at least: Alastair Hannay, [Kierkegaard: A Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=-pI8ueyxOSkC&pg=PA46) (2003), page 46:

> He [Søren] entered the university in October with the good grades in all his entry examinations expected of a pupil from the School of Civic Virtue, and with distinction (*laud prae ceteris*) in Greek, history, French, and – to his fellow-pupils’ great surprise – Danish composition. His first university examinations (the two-stage propaedeutic second examination [*Anden examen*], which he took in April and October 1831, the first examination being for his school-leaving diploma) embraced science as well as the liberal arts. The first part comprised Latin, Greek, Hebrew, history, and lower mathematics. He received *laud prae caeteris* in mathematics and *laudabilis* in all the others. The second part comprised theoretical philosophy, practical philosophy, physics, and
>   higher mathematics. Here he received *laud prae ceteris* in all subjects.

Comment: Good find. One should be aware of the fact that Hebrew at that time pretty much had been a dead language for centuries just like latin, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revival_of_the_Hebrew_language). Hence, it should not count as a spoken, but only written language in that list.